# How to create database structure for two column in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How to create database structure for two column.Please check below image and assist me how to create table and submition process.

[image]

Comment: "two column" or "two records / rows"?

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Ajeet.You can check the image demo1 and demo2 These are two column.If user submit the data form demo1 or demo2  no issue but admin should know that user submitted data from demo1 or demo2.

Comment: Mr.Ajeet Fname .LName etc field should be same for both demo1 and demo2

Comment: You suggest me.You have the image how to create table for this form?.I am a new in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table could have these columns: `user_id`, `fname`, `lname`, `email`, `mobile`, `city`, `website`, `demo_id`

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    lname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    mobile VARCHAR(15),
    city VARCHAR(100),
    demo_id INT(1) NOT NULL
)
```

When user submits the form (both demo1 and demo2), insert **two records** in table with `demo_id` value `1` for first record and `2` for second record in table.

But if both the form values are **always going to be same**, it is a **bad idea** to keep **duplicate** records (which differ only by `demo_id`). In such case, you can just insert only **one** record in table and provide a `demo_id` such as `1` when only demo1 was submitted, `2` when only demo2 was submitted and `3` when both demo forms were submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the below fileds in your table

`user_id, demo_type, fname, lname, email, mobile_num, city, website_url`

you can keep track of demo type in `demo_type` column so admin will know that user data is from which demo type

And for the submit process take two different submit buttons for both demo so when user will submit data you will easily get that from which demo user submited data and store that demo type in your db in `demo_type` column with other data like fname, lname etc.